# pyyaml converts mac address to number

Tags: python, ruby, yaml, pyyaml

I got this weird issue while loading a yaml file with a mac address where the address got converted to number.

```
>>> yaml.safe_load('abc: 11:00:00:00:00:00')
{'abc': 8553600000}
>>> yaml.safe_load('abc: 99:00:00:00:00:00')
{'abc': 76982400000}
```

But then I tried with following and I get answer as expected.

```
>>> yaml.safe_load('abc: ff:00:00:00:00:00')
{'abc': 'ff:00:00:00:00:00'}
```

I know solution for this which is to have the mac addresses inside quotes but I want to know reason for this behaviour.

Interestingly, I tried same data with ruby and got similar results.

**EDIT**

Adding new test data where it works with only numbers

```
>>> yaml.load('abc: 52:00:00:60:00:00')
{'abc': '52:00:00:60:00:00'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pyyaml`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml) works with YAML version 1.1 which supports [sexagecimal numbers](http://yaml.org/type/int.html), so positive integers lower than 60 separated with colons are considered as single number and you get its decimal presentation. If you want your MAC-addresses to be recognized as strings just add quotes like

```
>>>yaml.safe_load('abc: "11:00:00:00:00:00"')
{'abc': '11:00:00:00:00:00'}
```

Also there is [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which seems to support YAML version 1.2, where they've got rid of sexagecimals:

```
>>>import ruamel.yaml
>>>ruamel.yaml.safe_load('abc: 11:00:00:00:00')
{'abc': '11:00:00:00:00'}
```

Comment: `ruamel.yaml` wlll load sexagecimals if your YAML document starts with `%YAML 1.1` or specify that version as a parameter to `safe_load`, so  the package did not get rid of them. Sexagesimals are not in 1.2 and that is what `ruamel.yaml` defaults to, it also supports other 1.2 features such as `0o` for octals. (Disclaimer: I am "they" you are referring to).

Comment: @Anthon: I meant that in YAML 1.2 there are no sexagecimals, not in package ofc

Answer (score 1):

`11:00:00:00:00:00`    *(`11 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 60 =  8553600000`)*
`99:00:00:00:00:00`    *(`99 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 60 = 76982400000`)*
are considered to be *numbers* because they both begin with a *decimal number* and all other parts are decimal numbers from `0` to `59`.

`ff:00:00:00:00:00` is a *string* as it contains a *non-digit* (alphabetic) symbol.

`52:00:00:60:00:00` is a *string* as it contains a number *out of range of `0` to `59`* which is *not in the 1st position*.

To be more specific:

If the *first part* is an (arbitrary) decimal number and *all other parts* are numbers from `0` to `59`, it is supposed that *individual parts* (excluding the first) are digits in the positional numeral system of base `60`, so that it represents an *integer*.

In all other cases it is supposed to be a *string*.

Comment: yes i checked with safe_load as well and got same result as load